# How do I update FreeTDS driver in RHEL-like Docker image?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds

I am passing some emoticon data from a postgres database object to SQL Server 2016 using pyodbc.

Line 5 has my freeTDS driver I'm using.

```
def __insert_records(self, rows, target_fields):
        try:      
            mssql_connection = BaseHook.get_connection(self.mssql_conn_id)

            connection = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER='FreeTDS',host=mssql_connection.host,DATABASE=mssql_connection.schema,user=mssql_connection.login,password=mssql_connection.password,ClientCharset='utf-8',port=mssql_connection.port,driver='/usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so')
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            for i, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
                record = []

                for cell in row:
                    record.append(self._serialize_cell(cell))

                record_dictionary = self.__get_record_dictionary(record, target_fields)
               cursor.execute(self.__generate_insert_sql_statement(record_dictionary))

            connection.commit()

            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
        except pyodbc.ProgrammingError as programmingError:
            sqlstate = programmingError.args[0]
            if sqlstate = '42000':
                print(programmingError.args[0])
```

I need to update the driver (freeTDS) so that I can get around a bug when inserting emojis (related: https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/issues/317).

UPDATE: After accessing the CLI in my docker image, I ran tsql -C to get my compile time settings:

```
Version: freetds v1.1.20
```

Comment: What flavour of Linux are you using? Debian…? RHEL…?  …?

Comment: @GordThompson I'm using Docker, should I add my dockerfile code to this? It is having yum commands with freeTDS in it

Comment: @GordThompson after going into the CLI of my docker image, I ran tsql -C to get my compile time settings. I am having freetds v1.1.20, is that still going to have the driver truncate issue?

Comment: Apparently so. [This comment](https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/issues/317#issuecomment-560010097) indicates that the fix was included in version 1.1.23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently your Dockerfile already has the required commands to install pyodbc. Therefore your container should already have

- gcc-c++
- python3-devel
- unixODBC-devel

Now instead of installing freetds from EPEL (or wherever) your Dockerfile will need to perform the following (which uses the latest stable version of FreeTDS at the time of writing):

```
curl https://www.freetds.org/files/stable/freetds-1.2.18.tar.gz > freetds-1.2.18.tar.gz

tar -xvzf freetds-1.2.18.tar.gz

cd freetds-1.2.18/

./configure

make

sudo make install

echo "" | sudo tee -a /etc/odbcinst.ini > /dev/null

echo "[FreeTDS_1.2.18]" | sudo tee -a /etc/odbcinst.ini > /dev/null

echo "Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so" | sudo tee -a /etc/odbcinst.ini > /dev/null
```

Then you should be able to create a pyodbc connection like so:

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=FreeTDS_1.2.18;SERVER=192.168.0.179;PORT=49242;UID=sa;PWD=_whatever_;")
>>> print(cnxn.execute("SELECT @@VERSION").fetchval())
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583456) - 14.0.2037.2 (X64) 
    Nov  2 2020 19:19:59 
    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 8.1 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

>>> print(cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME))
libtdsodbc.so
>>> print(cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_VER))
01.02.0018
```